# Are time zone designators- "T" and "Z" case sensitive in ISO8601 format?

Tags: java, java-time, iso8601, datetimeformatter, offsetdatetime

I am using following ISO8601 format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
```

And I used `OffsetDateTime.parse()` to parse this format. I was able to parse date-time by passing `t` (instead of `T`) and `z` (instead of `Z`) here.

So can anyone tell if it is allowed in **ISO8601** or is it missed only in parsing logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So can anyone tell if it is allowed in ISO8601 or is it missed only in parsing logic?

I don't think it's valid to produce them though I guess it's fine (though not great) that the parser allows it.

The normative EBNF I have access to (8601-1 DIS Annex A) uses *only* uppercase latin letter for all designators, whether they be Z, T, W, R, P, Y, M, D, H, M, or S, and unlike (non-A) BNF, as far as I know EBNF terminals are case sensitive.

Comment: which version of ISO8601? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6 [first note] seems to imply that ISO allow lower case. But RFC-3339 is based on a old ISO8601

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it's the 2016 draft floating aound.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, ISO 8601:2004 *Data elements and interchange formats — Information interchange —Representation of dates and times*, page 11 says (and I quote):

> **NOTE 1** In date and time representations lower case characters may be used when upper case letters are not available.

The designators to which this would apply are enumerated on page 11, *ibid*:

- `P`: the duration designator, the use of `P` being based on the "historical" use of the term "period" for duration)
- `R`: the recurring time interval designator
- `T`: the time designator
- `W`: the week designator
- `Z`: the UTC designator (the use of `Z` being based on the common military, marine, and aviation usage of calling UTC "Zulu time").

Answer (score 2):

### `Z` is not the same as `z`.

`DateTimeFormatter` evaluates the former as **zone-offset** while the later as **time-zone name**.

Another example can be `M` which it uses for **month-of-year**, and `m` which it uses for **minute-of-hour**.

The symbol for the components of date, time, timezone etc. are case-sensitive. Check  [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn more about these symbols.

**A quick demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime odt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta"));
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(odt));
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz").format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-22T00:14:44+0530
2020-12-22T00:14:44IST
```

A zone offset is not the same as timezone. A timezone has an ID in the form, `Continent/City` e.g. `Asia/Calcutta` whereas a zone offset is represented in hours and minutes which tells how many hours and minutes the date & time of a place is offset from `UTC` date & time. Thus, many timezone IDs can have the same zone offset. In other words, a zone offset can be derived from the timezone ID but the converse is not possible e.g. in the following demo, `OffsetDateTime` will be able to determine the zone offset from the timezone ID of `Asia/Calcutta` but trying to get the timezone name (as in the above example) using `z` will fail.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta"));
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(odt));
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz").format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-22T00:30:40+0530
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract ZoneId from temporal 2020-12-22T00:30:40.865087+05:30
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:289)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$ZoneTextPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4072)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2341)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1843)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1817)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

> And I used "OffsetDateTime.parse()" (in java) to parse this format. I
> was able to parse date time by passing "t" (instead of "T") and "z"
> (instead of "Z") here.

I have already explained about `Z` and `z`. Let's focus on `T` and `t`. If you observe carefully, you will find that I've used single quotes around `T` i.e. `'T'` which makes it a string literal to be used inside the date-time string. It means that it can be anything e.g. `'t'` or `'Foo'` or `'Bar'`. As long as the literals in the `DateTimeFormatter` matches in the same case with that in the date-time string, it works without any problem. I've shown it in the following demo:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-12-22T00:45:50+05:30";

        // The given string is already in the format which is use by OffsetDateTime for
        // parsing without a DateTimeFormatter
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);

        // Let's try to parse it using different types of DateTimeFormatter instances
        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")));
        
        //The following line will fail as the literal does not match case-wise
        //System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd't'HH:mm:ssXXX")));
        
        strDateTime = "2020-12-22t00:45:50+05:30";// Now, DateTimeFormatter with 't' will work successfully
        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd't'HH:mm:ssXXX")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-22T00:45:50+05:30
2020-12-22T00:45:50+05:30
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

While I don’t know about ISO 8601 on this point, it is documented that Java’s one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse(CharSequence)` allows both upper and lower case `T` and `Z`.

### Tracing through the docs

The documentation says:

> The string must represent a valid date-time and is parsed using
> `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.

The documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` says that the format consists of:

> - The `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`
> - The offset ID. … Parsing is case insensitive.

The last sentence allows upper case `Z` and lower case `z` for offset. The documentation of `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` says about the `T`:

> - The letter 'T'. Parsing is case insensitive.

So this allows upper case `T` and lower case `t`.

We should not trust Java to tell us the truth about the standard. It seems that the ISO 8601 standard is a secret unless you pay for a copy (a funny way to persuade people to follow a standard IMHO). There’s a fine Wikipedia article on the standard. It gives the letters in upper case and does not mention whether they are allowed in lower case too.

### Links

- Java and java.time documentation

  - [`OffsetDateTime.parse(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))
  - [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
  - [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)